# Updating from Asymptote 2.61 to (current) 2.81

Tags: installing, asymptote, texshop, mactex

I have MacOSX Catalina (10.15.7). I'm currently using MacTeX-2022. Just today, I updated TeXShop to 4.78, the latest version.

I checked (via the terminal) my version of the package Asymptote; it is 2.61. However, the current version is 2.81. I need help in updating from 2.61 to 2.81. Specifically:

- **Can I go from 2.61 to 2.81 directly?**
- If I need to uninstall Asymptote before getting version 2.81, then **how do I do that**?
- Assuming I have uninstalled all versions of Asymptote, **how do I install version 2.81**? What exactly do I do with any "usr" folder that is created upon downloading Asymptote 2.81? Do I then need to do any commends? If so, which ones?

Thank you!

Comment: From when I used to use a Mac, my recollection is that MacTeX bundles a version of `asymptote`. MacTeX [supports multiple concurrent versions](https://tug.org/mactex/multipletexdistributions.html), so make sure you are really running 2022 and not earlier. That said, the bundled version is the same as in TeXLive, which is Asymptote 2.79. // [AoPS has some instructions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptote:_Macintosh) on how to install Asymptote from source; you can also use MacPorts or Homebrew.

Comment: Use the TeX Live Utility (found in /Applications/TeX) supplied by MacTeX to update your TeX Live 2022 (which is what is installed by MacTeX). This should update you to the latest released version, 2.79.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I used to terminal to verify that I have TeX Live 2022. However, when I used the terminal to check the version of Asymptote ("asy --version"), it says that I have version 2.61, not 2.79.

Comment: @N1G : did you update using TeX Live Utility?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Yes, I selected the asymptote package, reinstalled it, and then checked the version via the terminal; it is still version 2.61.

Comment: @N1G : What do `which pdflatex` and `ls -alf  /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex` return?

Comment: @HerbSchulz The first returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`. The second returns `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  6 Jun 13 12:52 /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex -> pdftex`.

Comment: @N1G : Have you ever used TeX Live Utility to do a general update of all packages in  you TeX Live 2022 distribution? When you start up TeX Live Utility it should give you a list of all the packages that have been updated since your last update.  Also, did you have another TeX distribution installed at any time; what does `which asy` return?

Comment: @HerbSchulz When I do `which asy`, I get `/opt/local/bin/asy`. 

I have used TeX Live Utility to keep packages updated, yes. It does give me a list of all packages that have been updated since the last update (which I did prior to checking my version of Asymptote). For years now, I've only ever used MacTeX.

Comment: @N1G : It appears you have a version of ash installed by something else (MacPorts?) that is interfering with one in TeX Live. You need to either uninstall it or prepend your path with `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Comment: @N1G : Of course that should have been asy, not ash.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Sorry for taking a while to reply. I have been at the hospital recently. I'm not sure how to do either of those things, but I'll do some digging and see what I can come up with. Thank you!

Comment: @N1G : Sorry to hear about your hospital visit. As a temporary alternative, run `/Library/TeX/texbin/asy` rather than `asy` alone. That picks out the correct version of asy; try `/Library/TeX/texbin/asy --version` to check. A TEMPORARY fix only.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Ah, so `/Library/TeX/texbin/asy --version` returned version 2.79, while `asy --version` returned 2.70. Is there an easy way on a Mac to get TeXShop to actually use the correct version (2.79 here)? I'm sorry, but my skills in doing this are not the best.

Comment: How are you getting TeXShop to use asy at all? Are you using one of the latexmk based engines, (pdf/xe/lua)latexmk, and a platexmkrc file?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I am using an asymptote engine that I removed from being inactive to active.

Comment: @N1G : Ok. Open up ~/Library/TeXShop (You can use TeXShop's `TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop` menu command for that. Then Open the `bin` folder and then the  `tslatexmk` folder. You should see a file called `asymptotemkrc`. Drop that file onto TeXShop to open it for editing. There is a line that says `   sub asy2x { return system("asy '$_[0]'"); }` change it to be `   sub asy2x { return system("/Library/TeX/texbin/asy '$_[0]'"); }` and save that file. Hopefully it will now work with the proper version of asy.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I was able to make and save that change; however, it did not produce the correct output for figures. Also, `asy --version` still returns version 2.70, if that matters.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Should I uninstall all of MacPorts? (I installed MacPorts about two years ago when I ran into trouble with Asymptote. It was recommended to me at that time to try MacPorts.)

Comment: @N1G : First, please copy that fixed line here so I can check it. Second, I can’t really answer the second question because I don’t know what you installed with MacPorts or if you actually use it.

Comment: @HerbSchulz `sub asy2x { return system("/Library/TeX/texbin/asy '$_[0]'"); }`

Comment: @N1G : That change will NOT change the asy version used in Terminal. It will force the use of the proper `/Library/TeX/texbin/asy` when used with the `aymptotemk` engine in TeXShop. When you say it "fails to to produce the correct output" what do you mean?

Comment: @HerbSchulz My surfaces are not transparent; in fact, they are barely being shaded at all.

Comment: @N1G : So the compilation completes. That means the engine is working properly. Maybe someone else can help with that problem.

Comment: @N1G : Note: today there was an update to asymptote to work with Ghostscript 2.56. That might fix your problem. Use TeX Live Utilkity to update your TeX Distgribution.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Okay, so I used TeX Live Utility, which I do once each week, and so the asymptote package was updated. However, I'm now getting an error when I go to typset the file. If the file is called hello.tex, then the error says that hello-1_0 is not found. It also includes `\includegraphics{ASYprefix\jobname-1_0}%` in the error. (Thank you for still trying to help!)

Comment: @N1G : where did you get this sample? Do you have a graphic file hello-1_0.* where * can be jpg, pdf, etc? Can I get hold of that file and any included graphics?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Sure, I can send you the actual .tex file, a PDF of the original output, and a PDF of the current actual output. Should I email them to you? If so, can you give me your address? Thank you!

Comment: @N1G : I'd need that graphic file too. Let me find out a decent way to do the transfer. I assume that `\includegraphics` command is in a asymptote figure.